# connecting to mysql from excel: ODBC driver does not support the requested properties

Tags: sql, mysql, excel, vba, odbc

i am trying to add data to mysql from excel. i am getting the above error on this line: rs.Open strSQL, oConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

here is my code:

```
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection

Private Sub ConnectDB()
    Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
    oConn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};" & _
        "SERVER=localhost;" & _
        "DATABASE=employees;" & _
        "USER=root;" & _
        "PASSWORD=some_pass;" & _
        "Option=3"

End Sub

Function esc(txt As String)
    esc = Trim(Replace(txt, "'", "\'"))
End Function


Private Sub InsertData()
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    ConnectDB
    With wsBooks
        For rowCursor = 2 To 11
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO tutorial (author, title, price) " & _
                "VALUES ('" & esc(.Cells(rowCursor, 1)) & "', " & _
                "'" & esc(.Cells(rowCursor, 2)) & "', " & _
                esc(.Cells(rowCursor, 3)) & ")"
            rs.Open strSQL, oConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

whats wrong with rs.Open strSQL, oConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic ?
why am i getting the odbc error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

INSERT does not return a recordset. Use oConn.Execute to do this kind of insert.

Another option might be the this particular version of mysql driver does not support adOpenDynamic (are you sure you need it?) or adLockOptimistic (same).

But anyway, this code is an [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) hole. You should consider using parametrised queries:

```
dim cm as adodb.command
set cm=new adodb.command
set cm.activeconnection = oConn
cm.commandtype = adcmdtext
cm.commandtext = "insert tutorial (author, title, price) values (?,?,?)"
cm.parameters.add cm.createparameter(,adVarChar,adParamInput,50,esc(.Cells(rowCursor, 1)))
cm.parameters.add cm.createparameter(,adVarChar,adParamInput,50,esc(.Cells(rowCursor, 2)))
cm.parameters.add cm.createparameter(,adDouble,adParamInput,,esc(.Cells(rowCursor, 3)))

cm.execute ,, adExecuteNoRecords
```